# how to delete property using CQ.Extjs

Tags: extjs, aem

I want to delete a property of a node, so I have written something like this -

```
    var params={};
    var propKey="somekey"+"@Delete";
    params[propKey] = "some value";
    params["_charset_"] ="utf-8";

    $CQ.post("/path/to/my/node",params,null);
```

above code is not deleting from the node. Kindly advice!

Answer (score 1):

`some value` should actually be `null`, otherwise the property has a value and won't be deleted. The type hint only works for the empty values, like `null`.

```
var params={};
params["somekey"+"@Delete"] = null;
params["_charset_"] ="utf-8";
$CQ.post("/path/to/my/node", params, null);
```

Comment: thank you for your help! as per my requirement, I have to delete a property of a node which has value, will it be not possible in this way?

Comment: beautifulday, use `null` instead of `""` in the second line.

Comment: The same thing I tried but it did not work for me, it worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it works just as the empty string does. But: what which property do you want to delete?

Comment: I want to delete a property of a user directory node. For example this node '/home/users/s/someuser' has a prop named 'somekey', so I want to delete 'somekey'.

Comment: The above solution works, when the user may modify the node. This is handled via access management, ACLs, respectively. Test if the code works as `admin` and if check the logs, why it does not works for an authenticated user. Anonymous users won't be able to do it.

Comment: this user has jcr:all permission on this node and it is not an anonymous user. However, if I try to delete another node(nt:unstructured) prop which is under  '/home/users/s/someuser/anothernode' then it works fine. But it does not work for rep:User node type, any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Please try it as `admin` to verify that it does not work. If it does work, ensure that `rep:write` (aggregates `jcr:write` and `jcr:nodeTypeManagement`) is part of the user's permissions. It might also be the case, that deleting that specific property does not work (similar to `jcr:primaryType`). Since you never said, which property is is targeted, it's basically all just guessing.